# NavigationDrawer selection issue in Android 2.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

This is how my NavigationDrawer list item is defined.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list_item_title"
            style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="#00FFFF"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list_item_subtitle"
            style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using ActionBarSherlock library along with **[SherlockNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer)**.

Everything is working perfectly in my Android 4.3 device.

But in my 2.3.3 device, I am experiencing a strange issue.

This is how the initial NavigationDrawer looks.

[image]

**Problem scenario :** I press and hold any listItem and then drag my finger (while still holding down) up or down towards another listItem.

That is when this happens.

[image]

***All the listItems get highlighted in white*** and it remains like like until and unless another listItem is clicked in the normal way (even if I close and reopen the NavDrawer, still the whole list remains highlighted in white).

This does not happen in Android 4.3 though.

It happens only in Android 2.3.3 (maybe happens on all pre-ICS devices).

Is it an issue with the compatibility library ?

This is the only additional code I have in values-v11 folder, because "activatedBackgroundIndicator" is not available in Android 2.3.

```
<resources>
    <style name="listViewActivatedStyle">
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Android 2.3 does not get access to the above code. Is that the reason it is giving this issue ? Or there is a bug in the compatibility library?

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you found a solution, cause I've got the same problem with my navigation drawer ? 
The `cacheColorHint` ain't working for me

Comment: Well, it was already working for me. You could give a shot to `android:cacheColorHint="@null"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` and see what you get.

Comment: I already tried `android:cacheColorHint="@null"` 
And I can't use `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` cause I'm already using this `android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_selector" `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add

```
android:cacheColorHint="@null"
```

to the list

Comment: Wow! Great! No more of that ugly white all over the list! Thanks! But there one minor problem though. When the listItem is clicked, there is no change in the appearance of the listItem. I mean, the user can't really know which was clicked. Any way to resolve that ?

Comment: Fixed it! Adding just the `android:cacheColorHint="@null"` let the click animation persist. Thank you very much for the help. I was beating my head thinking it was something about the compatibility library. Thanks again! :)